# How to call function if condition is true kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, if-statement

Right now in my project I have such functions calls:

```
if (theme.isNotEmpty() && body.isNotEmpty()) {
   sendToCons()
}
if (theme.isEmpty() && body.isEmpty()) {
   alertDialog(getString(R.string.alert_1), 0)
}
if (theme.isNotEmpty() && body.isEmpty()) {
   alertDialog(getString(R.string.alert_2), 0)
}
if (theme.isEmpty() && body.isNotEmpty()) {
   alertDialog(getString(R.string.alert_3), 0)
}
```

this code scope I changed to this one:

```
when {
      theme.isNotEmpty() && body.isNotEmpty() -> sendToCons()
      theme.isEmpty() && body.isEmpty() -> alertDialog(getString(R.string.alert_1), 0)
      theme.isNotEmpty() && body.isEmpty() -> alertDialog(getString(R.string.alert_2), 0)
      theme.isEmpty() && body.isNotEmpty() -> alertDialog(getString(R.string.alert_3), 0)
}
```

And maybe kotlin has some methods for calling functions if condition is true? I thought that I will solve this problem with `.run{condition}` but when I do it:

```
alertDialog(getString(R.string.alert_1), 0).run{theme.isEmpty() && body.isEmpty()}
```

my `alerDialog` function was called two times. Maybe I did smth wrong or kotlin has another mechanism for it?

Comment: `And maybe kotlin has some methods for calling functions if condition is true?` this is exactly what the `if`/`when` statement does. Can you provide more information on what you need and why?

Comment: @IR42, I'm thinking about possible conditions optimization for this code scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no optimal optimization for your code, you can use **if** or **when** statements for conditions. If you want some tricky function which evaluates conditions, you can create an extension function on **Boolean**:

```
inline fun Boolean.then(block: () -> R) {
    if (this) {
        block()
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
(theme.isNotEmpty() && body.isNotEmpty()).then { sendToCons() }
(theme.isEmpty() && body.isEmpty()).then { alertDialog(getString(R.string.alert_1), 0) }
```

Answer (score 2):

The variant using `when` is different from the sequence of `if`s in that exactly one branch is executed. With the `if`s multiple branches can be executed if their respective conditions evaluate to `true`. 
Depending on if you want just 1 branch executed or allow multiple ones, I would keep the code using `if`s or `when`.
`run` does not serve for branching at all. It allows you to call some functions on an object without assigning it to a variable because the object becomes the implicit `this` variable.